# Pydantic validations for extra fields that not defined in schema

Tags: python, validation, pydantic

I am using pydantic for schema validations and I would like to throw an error when any extra field is added to a schema that isn't defined.

```
from typing import Literal, Union

from pydantic import BaseModel, Field, ValidationError


class Cat(BaseModel):
    pet_type: Literal['cat']
    meows: int


class Dog(BaseModel):
    pet_type: Literal['dog']
    barks: float


class Lizard(BaseModel):
    pet_type: Literal['reptile', 'lizard']
    scales: bool


class Model(BaseModel):
    pet: Union[Cat, Dog, Lizard] = Field(..., discriminator='pet_type')
    n: int


print(Model(pet={'pet_type': 'dog', 'barks': 3.14, 'eats': 'biscuit'}, n=1))
""" try:
    Model(pet={'pet_type': 'dog'}, n=1)
except ValidationError as e:
    print(e) """
```

In the above code, I have added the `eats` field which is not defined. The pydantic validations are applied and the extra values that I defined are removed in response. I wanna throw an error saying `eats is not allowed for Dog` or something like that. Is there any way to achieve that?

And is there any chance that we can provide the input directly instead of the `pet` object?
`print(Model({'pet_type': 'dog', 'barks': 3.14, 'eats': 'biscuit', n=1}))`. I tried without `descriminator` but those specific validations are missing related to `pet_type`. Can someone guide me how to achive either one of that?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You can use the [`extra` field](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/model_config/#options) in the `Config` class to *forbid* extra attributes during model initialisation (by default, additional attributes will be *ignored*).

For example:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, Extra

class Pet(BaseModel):
    name: str

    class Config:
        extra = Extra.forbid

data = {
    "name": "some name",
    "some_extra_field": "some value",
}

my_pet = Pet.parse_obj(data)   # <- effectively the same as Pet(**pet_data)
```

will raise a `VaidationError`:

```
ValidationError: 1 validation error for Pet
some_extra_field
  extra fields not permitted (type=value_error.extra)
```

Works as well when the model is "nested", e.g.:

```py
class PetModel(BaseModel):
    my_pet: Pet
    n: int

pet_data = {
    "my_pet": {"name": "Some Name", "invalid_field": "some value"},
    "n": 5,
}

pet_model = PetModel.parse_obj(pet_data)
# Effectively the same as
# pet_model = PetModel(my_pet={"name": "Some Name", "invalid_field": "some value"}, n=5)
```

will raise:

```
ValidationError: 1 validation error for PetModel
my_pet -> invalid_field
  extra fields not permitted (type=value_error.extra)
```

Comment: this needs a 2023 update: The config class no longer exists

Answer (score 17):

The preferred solution is to use a `ConfigDict` (ref. the [documentation](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/usage/model_config)):

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, ConfigDict

class Pet(BaseModel):
    model_config = ConfigDict(extra='forbid')

    name: str
```

[Paul P's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71838453/5930169) still works (for now), but the `Config` class has been deprecated in pydantic v2.0.
Another deprecated solution is `pydantic.Extra.forbid`.

One advantage of the method above is that it can be type checked.

Answer (score 0):

Pydantic is made to validate your input with the schema. In your case, you want to remove one of its validation feature.

I think you should create a new class that inherit from `BaseModel`

```
class ModifiedBaseModel(BaseModel):
    def __init__(__pydantic_self__, **data: Any) -> None:
        registered, not_registered = __pydantic_self__.filter_data(data)
        super().__init__(**registered)
        for k, v in not_registered.items():
            __pydantic_self__.__dict__[k] = v
    
    @classmethod
    def filter_data(cls, data):
        registered_attr = {}
        not_registered_attr = {}
        annots = cls.__annotations__
        for k, v in data.items():
            if k in annots:
                registered_attr[k] = v
            else:
                not_registered_attr[k] = v
        return registered_attr, not_registered_attr
```

then create your validation classes

```
class Cat(ModifiedBaseModel):
    pet_type: Literal['cat']
    meows: int
```

now you can create a new `Cat` without worries about undefined attribute. Like this

```
my_cat = Cat(pet_type='cat', meows=3, name='blacky', age=3)
```

---

2nd question, to put the input directly from `dict` you can use double asterisk `**`

```
Dog(**my_dog_data_in_dict)
```

or

```
Dog(**{'pet_type': 'dog', 'barks': 3.14, 'eats': 'biscuit', n=1})
```